# anchoring a beam made from dimensional lumber to concrete piers

Tags: concrete, construction, shed, anchor, terminology

The rim joists of a shed will sit on two horizontal beams. The beams need to be secured to concrete piers with some kind of galvanized tie. Something like the one in the picture.

The beams will be created by flipping three (US nominal) 2x6 on edge and "laminating" them together, so to speak. A nominal 2x6 is approximately 1½ by 5½. So the beam is 4½ inches thick.

Are any such ties specifically designed to work with *dimensional* (2x) lumber, that is, such that the actual width of the tie is a multiple of ~1½ inches? If so, is there a term of art for such ties?

A tie with a 4" actual space, for example, is too small to accommodate three 2x6.

[image: concrete anchor]

Comment: I would go for taller horizontal beams, Either 2x8 or 2x10, double them up, add a shim into the galvanized tie by planing down a piece of wood or use plywood. I haven't done the load calculations for a 6x6 (your plan) versus 4x8 or 4x10 (my suggestion) but I would bet it will be more than sufficient.

Comment: Also, If your beam length is 8 feet or less then it would be trivial to buy plywood and sandwich it in between the 2x6 lumber to give you the thickness desired.

Comment: In my experience, _every. single. one._ of these is designed for 2-by dimensional lumber. If it's designed for one, it's got a 1.5" internal space, for two it has 3" internal space, for 3 it has 4.5" internal space. Don't know that I've ever seen one that is an actual internal dimension of 4" - a 4x4 post is 3.5", so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Freeman: I was on tech support phone call earlier this morning with a major manufacturer of these anchors and they said just the opposite of what you stated.  Me: "Are your 4" dimensions actual or nominal? Would three 2x6 flipped fit?"  Tech support: "They're actual.  Three 2x6 would not fit."   Then I got a reply from another tech agent at the company in which he wrote that with their larger size, I would need a shim.

Comment: Weird. I've gotten mine from the local big-box (never dealt directly with the factory) and have never had an issue. I guess you'll be buying some sheets of 1/2" PT plywood and ripping it into shims. Or, look at a different manufacturer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus:  The manufacturer told me not to use 2x6 but to use a 2x8 with one of their anchors because the fastener would be too close to the edge of the beam and could cause splintering, so I will probably go up to 8" as you have suggested.

Comment: Sounds good. I highly doubt that the anchor you posted is 4 inch actual. It's extremely likely that it's 3.5 inches designed to be used with a nominal 4 by something. So if you cannot find a nominal 4x8 then 2 nominal 2x8s would need to be shimmed with a half inch of something.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Sorry, that was just a random picture I grabbed from the www to show the general kind of anchor I had in mind.

Comment: I understand that. In general I would be surprised that any manufacturer would produce an anchor that is actually 4 inches wide unless it was special ordered. Nominal wood is sold in stores so it would make the most sense to sell nominal anchors :-)

Comment: Quite frankly, if you have a local hardware store then grab your tape measure and pay a visit. You will learn far more in 5 minutes at the store than the presumed hour on this site :-)

Comment: In my town we must have an engineer sign off.  I want to keep the shed narrow at 8' (not to encroach on a beloved badminton playing area) and low at around 11-1/2' height, but long at 24'.  Engineer I've connected with over the www is suggesting eight(8) 18" diameter sonotubes sunk 4' deep (yikes) which makes for 88 80-lb bags of concrete (over 7000 pounds). If I used a slab instead all that would be needed is ten anchor bolts spaced 6' apart going through the sill plate. Not sure how he's getting to that size sonotube when a beam-anchor is much stronger than single sill-plate bolts.

Comment: At the moment I am without a car, but seeing the thing is better than reading a PDF, for sure.

Comment: 4 feet deep? Sounds like there are frost-line requirements in your area. I'm not saying to ignore the engineer in any way, I'm just saying that I highly doubt they are forcing you to use 4 inch actual lumber.

Comment: Frost-depth here is 36". I think the engineer is not fine-tuning anything but is going for overkill.

Comment: Did you ever get an satisfactory solution to this problem. I have the same question.

Comment: @bhspencer: I never found a mounting shoe that was designed from the get-go to be used with dimensional lumber sandwiched together, without shimming.  How we were going to handle the issue was never finalized because the shed build was postponed when another need arose with higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need. Check with the representative from Simpson for availability and what size (W) you need. You can filter the desirable size from the table below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The chart highlights the very question I asked about 2x dimensional lumber compatibility. The "W" dimension is not a multiple of 1-1/2, to make it perfectly suited to dimensional 2x lumber. These are post ties that are being *repurposed* as beam anchors. The ABW66Z at 5-1/2" is probably the best bet for a triple 2x6 beam, but there would be about an inch of space to be shimmed.

Comment: @mr blint I don't know why you need to sit the beam directly on the concrete pier. You shall consider attaching your beam to a post, then connect the post using the post connector as shown. Otherwise, you might have to make your own connector then.

Comment: A number of things, but mainly height of the building.When a shed is set closer than 10' from property line here, the max height is 11 feet. I wanted to use cedar shingles at standard exposure, so minimum pitch is 4 in 12.  I have to solve the problem in a manner that the local inspector would approve, so there has to be published load specs.

Comment: @mr blink If the concrete pier hasn't poured yet, you might consider embed a short piece of wood post and connect the beam to it with standard connectors.

Comment: Embedding wood into the concrete pier defeats the purpose of the post base - keeping the wood _away_ from the concrete, thus extending its life span.